# Find path between disconnected points

Tags: java, graph, geometry, cartesian-coordinates

My challenge is to find the shortest path between two points **A** and **B** in a cartesian plan, tracing the path across the other points, respecting the following:
1) There's no edges (disconnected graph);
2) The distance between two "neighbors" points cannot be greater than a specified value (For example `P16->B`).

In this case:

```
A
   P1      P2      P3      P4      P5
   P7    
   P8      P9      P16                 B
       P10                     P15
           P11     P12     P13     P14
```

the path should be:

```
A->P1->P2->P3->P4->P5->B
```

My first try was to iterate over all nodes, creating edges and after this, applying the dijkstra algorithm. But it seems to be very slow for big graphs.

```
for(Point ori : points)
    for(Point dest : points)
        if(!ori.equals(dest) && distance(ori, dest) <= maxDistance))
            ori.neighbors.add(dest);

List<Point> path = dijkstra(points, pointA, pointB);
```

There's another best solution?

Comment: Why isn't the answer the shorter path `A->P1->P9->P16->B`?

Comment: Or the even shorter path `A->P1->B` (assuming the points are laid out in a representation of their actual positions).  Or even shorter: `A->B`?  The problem is underspecified unless you know what paths between points are permitted and which are not, and if all paths are permitted, then any path that deviates from `A->B` will of necessity be longer.

Comment: Because in this example I try to explain that the path cannot have edges with size greater than the max permitted between two points. P1 is too far from B.

Comment: The only obvious optimization is to interleave Dijkstra with reachable neighbor identification, although this probably wouldn't save a huge amount of time.

Comment: You could build a kD-tree or quadtree of the points, and for each point search for neighbors contained in a circle with radius equal to the maximum distance; [Here](http://thomasdiewald.com/blog/?p=1689#) is an example. This will reduce the graph-building time complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(n log n)` (for relatively sparse point-sets)